# How is this realised?

Tags: theming

When we implement, for example, `theme_preprocess_page(&$vars)` function, we can alter variable that are visible as not array items.

What I mean: `$vars['somevalue']` from `theme_preprocess_page(&$vars)` function is further  available in `page.tpl.php` as `$somevalue`. How is it possible? Definitely there is some kind of automatic generation of variables but the implementation is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme engine runs the variables array through [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), which extracts each key/value pair to a variable in the local scope.

For example, running the following code:

```
$array = array('var1' => 1, 'var2' => 2, 'var3' => 3);
extract($array);
```

will give you access to these three variables in the local scope:

```
$var1 // equal to 1
$var2 // equal to 2
$var3 // equal to 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Clive's answer is correct. I am just pointing out where exactly that happens.

[theme_render_template()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_render_template/7) is the function called by [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7), and it contains the following code.

```
  extract($variables, EXTR_SKIP); // Extract the variables to a local namespace
  ob_start(); // Start output buffering
  include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $template_file; // Include the template file
  return ob_get_clean(); // End buffering and return its contents
```

The code that calls `theme_render_template()` is the following one.

```
    // Default render function and extension.
    $render_function = 'theme_render_template';
    $extension = '.tpl.php';

    // The theme engine may use a different extension and a different renderer.
    global $theme_engine;
    if (isset($theme_engine)) {
      if ($info['type'] != 'module') {
        if (function_exists($theme_engine . '_render_template')) {
          $render_function = $theme_engine . '_render_template';
        }
        $extension_function = $theme_engine . '_extension';
        if (function_exists($extension_function)) {
          $extension = $extension_function();
        }
      }
    }

    // In some cases, a template implementation may not have had
    // template_preprocess() run (for example, if the default implementation is
    // a function, but a template overrides that default implementation). In
    // these cases, a template should still be able to expect to have access to
    // the variables provided by template_preprocess(), so we add them here if
    // they don't already exist. We don't want to run template_preprocess()
    // twice (it would be inefficient and mess up zebra striping), so we use the
    // 'directory' variable to determine if it has already run, which while not
    // completely intuitive, is reasonably safe, and allows us to save on the
    // overhead of adding some new variable to track that.
    if (!isset($variables['directory'])) {
      $default_template_variables = array();
      template_preprocess($default_template_variables, $hook);
      $variables += $default_template_variables;
    }

    // Render the output using the template file.
    $template_file = $info['template'] . $extension;
    if (isset($info['path'])) {
      $template_file = $info['path'] . '/' . $template_file;
    }
    $output = $render_function($template_file, $variables);
  }
```

Comment: Nice one, I always wondered where that happened but I could never be bothered to find out!